# Activate onchange with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to activate the onchange on a select when I change the value of it with jquery.
It does work when I select another option in it. But when I give it another value with jquery it doesn't see it as a change which I do need it to see it as.

Sorry I can't explain it that well but here is the code:

HTML:

```
<select id="autoFiller">
    <option>Hello</option>
    <option>Bye</option>
</select>

<br />

<select id="affect">
    <option>Test1</option>
    <option>Test2</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    $("#autoFiller").change(function () {
        $("#affect").val("Test2");
    });

    $("#affect").change(function () {
        alert("Hello");
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CTwcC/1/

Like in the demo when I change the second select it does give an alert. But I need the second one to alert when I change the first one too through the second select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `.change()` on the select.

```
$(function () {
    $("#autoFiller").change(function () {
        $("#affect").val("Test2").change();
    });

    $("#affect").change(function () {
        alert("Hello");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CTwcC/2/

Comment: Wow such an easy solution thanks a lot helps me tons!